# Avoid pgrep in sh

Tags: shell-script, grep, aix

```
#!/bin/sh
ALTER="$1"
NAME="$2"

for pr in $(pgrep $NAME); do 
    elapse=$(ps -o etime= -p $pr)
    [ "${elapse%-*}" -gt "$ALTER" ] && echo $pr
done
```

I am running this on AIX which doesn't support `pgrep`. How can I do the above without `pgrep`?

Answer (score 1):

Well, with a standard linux [`procps-ng`](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps) `ps` binary, *I* can avoid it like:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
ALTER="$1" NAME="$2" IFS=' 
'
set -- $(ps -opid=,etime= -C"$NAME")
while  [ 0  -lt   $# ]
do     case $2 in (*-*)
       [ "${2%-*}" -gt "$ALTER" ] &&
       printf %d\\n "$1"
       esac; shift 2
done
```

I don't know *what* `ps` ships with AIX, but it probably isnt that. You can definitely get pids from any POSIX `ps`. It just requires a little more work.

```
set -- $(
    ps -Aocomm=,pid=,etime= |
    sed -ne "s/^$NAME  *//p"
)
```

...should substitute in perfectly with a POSIX `ps` and a POSIX `sed`.

I do like just doing `ps -C"$NAME"`, though, and don't understand why anyone uses `pgrep` anyway.

Comment: procps-ng's `ps -C` (though that ps -C comes from HP/UX I believe) would be a bit like `pgrep -x`, though `pgrep` would still do a ERE match. `ps -C "foo bar"` matches on processes whose process name is foo or bar. `pgrep "foo bar"` would return the processes whose name matches the `foo bar` ERE (so here _contain_ `foo bar`). Note that `pgrep` can match on much more than the process name, so it's still quite useful.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - oh. that's a very good point. i never did use it like that, but i might now. seems i missed the whole point of the name, huh?

Comment: Note that `ps -o cmd` would be the procps-ng equivalent of POSIX's `ps -o args`. You probably meant `ps -o comm` which is meant to be the argv[0], but with procps-ng is the process name instead. `pgrep` and `ps -C` search the process name as well.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - thanks again! i almost did write in `comm=` but then i checked `cmd=` in the terminal and there were no arguments. i was a little confused, but went with it. i'll fix it now. you're a super smart guy, by the way. one other thing confuses me, actually. why do you figure OP does `"${var%-*}"` with the `-`dash? i *think* i'm doing approximately the same by putting the seconds in `$3` with `:` in `$IFS` and leaving them out of the calculation. what do you think? basically i just don't like command subs in loops...

Comment: oh. i looked harder at some etime= stuff and apparently the dashes show up for days' old processes. i assume that `$ALTER` is meant to measured in days all of the time, too.  so the `$IFS` thing was maybe misguided. i need to pull it.

Comment: Check the OP's question history. His question has been answered several times, probably not much point spending too much time on it as he may very well ask it yet another way soon

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - well it should work as is. I just never noticed dashes in `ps` output for execution time before - i guess the kinds of processes that manage to hang around for days just aren't especially interesting to me. so i just added that `case` statement to do explicitly the error prone bit of parsing i was doing before. i think i get it now - i just didnt know what the dash was for.

Answer (score 0):

You could always try parsing `ps` itself:

```
ps -xa -o "%p %a %t" | 
    awk -vname="$NAME" -valt="${ALTER}" '
        $0~name && $0!~ARGV[0]{
            sub("-.*","",$NF); 
            if($NF > alt){print $1}
        }'
```

The `ps` command will print the PID, process arguments (including process name) and the elapsed time. These are then passed to `awk` which also receives the values for `NAME` (`name` in the awk script: `-vname="$NAME"`) and `$ALTER` (`alt` in the awk script: `valt="$ALTER"`). If a line matches `name` (`$0~name`) and is not the awk process itself (`$0!~ARGV[0]`), remove everything after the first `-` from the last field (`sub("-.*","",$NF);`) and, if the remaining part of the last field is greater than `$ALTER` (`if($NF > alt)`), print the the 1st field (the PID).

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use ps aux and it looks like this now:

```
for pr in $(ps aux | grep $NAME | awk '{print$2}')
```

and this actually seems to work!

Comment: depending on race conditions you may actually pull in the `grep` cmd you're running because `"$NAME"` will match as one of `grep`'s arguments. You should specify your output specifically - it's much easier, and you were doing it before anyway. `ps -A -o comm=,pid=,etime=` will print only three fields for `-A`ll running processes: the `comm`and name *(no args)*, the pid number, and the execution time. you can `grep` that output without any danger of pulling your `grep` in *(unless `NAME=grep`, of course)* - and it will come with the other fields you want, too.